# Deriving from Doppler's formula

Tags: algebra-precalculus, physics, problem-solving

I am studying Doppler sonography. I do understand doppler's formula:
$$
f=f_{0}\frac{v}{v-u},
$$
where $f_{0}$ is emitted frequency, *f* is received frequency, *v* is speed of the ultrasound puls and *u* is speed of blood from which is the ultrasound puls bouncing back.
But I am struggling with how to get from above formula to this:
$$
\Delta f = f-f_{0}=2f_{0}u.
$$
Can anyone one give me hint? Thank you.

[Image I am working with](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TPAQW.png)

Comment: That does not look right. $f-f_0 = f_{0}\frac{v}{v-u} - f_0 = f_{0}\frac{u}{v-u}$ is *not* equal to $2 f_0 u$.

Comment: Then I misinterpreted the image I added to my question probably.

Comment: It looks like the image is trying to sat $\Delta F=2F_Tv/c$.

Comment: Ok, this makes more sense.. but still is this formula directly derived from $$
f=f_{0}\frac{v}{v-u}?
$$